# Form Creation in SharePoint 2013 Standard Version

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, form

I have read this article http://blogs.office.com/b/sharepoint/archive/2013/03/04/options-to-create-forms-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx about options to create forms in SharePoint 2013. I learned that configuring and publishing InfoPath form is only available in SharePoint Enterprise version (http://www.appvity.com/blogs/post/2013/06/16/How-to-configure-and-publish-InfoPath-to-SharePoint-2013.aspx).

My question is: is it possible to create forms (without using Visual Studio) in SharePoint 2013 Standard version? We only have power users, not programmers, so we would like an option that enables us to create forms even without programming knowledge. Thanks!

Comment: Open for third party solutions?

Comment: Well, I am not still aware of the third party solutions as I am new to SharePoint @ArsalanAdamKhatri. I might as well stick with the Microsoft products first. :)

Comment: I have same question. My farm is std 2013. Can I use Infopath to amend forms and workflows?

Comment: @Mark As far as I can remember, you'll be needing an Enterprise version of SP then use InfoPath. See my comment on the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without some programming or markup knowledge, you would need Enterprise for InfoPath or go a third-party solution route (there are a few third-party forms solutions that might work for you).

With a little bit of markup and programming knowledge, you could use SharePoint Designer to edit the New/Edit/View forms of a list.  You could also create a form in HTML and use JavaScript to do the validation and submission.  If either of these options are worth pursuing, we can provide more details on how you could use either option.

Comment: I just saw a very useful article: http://go.limeleap.com/community/bid/300409/SharePoint-Forms-Comparison-Lists-vs-SP-Designer-vs-InfoPath. I understand now. Therefore, if I am to pursue the easiest way (which is InfoPath), I'd rather purchase the Enterprise version.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but there is a new solution by Mark Rackley & co.  The source code is practically cut an paste and allows some really neat customizations.  See also his [Stratus Forms](http://www.stratusforms.com/)

http://www.markrackley.net/2017/05/04/customize-your-sharepoint-classic-forms-without-infopath/

Comment: Finally a solution after 4 years. :D

Comment: It really is a lovely solution!